# Interpretation of GLMM summary in R

Tags: logistic, lme4-nlme, interpretation, glmm

I have serious difficulty understanding the default R-summary of a GLMM model from the `lme4` package.

1. First of all, I would like to know how to interpret the information given in the summary output. What are the siginficant values here? In particular, the sections **Scaled residuals**, **Random Effects**, **Fixed Effects** and **Signif. Codes**.
2. Which point of the output tells something about whether the model is appropriate for describing the data set?
3. In case that the output does not provide enough information for deciding whether the model is appropriate or not, which R-command can provide such information?
4. What is the meaning of the column **Corr** in the section Random Effects? Are these values significant? If yes, in which sense?

In the analysis below, the variable `Ausfall` takes only two values: 0 and 1. The variables `WZ2` and `umsatz2` take discrete
values (`umsatz2` takes values from 1 to 10). `ROIm_r` can take any real value.

The output is:

```
library(lme4)
library(mgcv)
GLMM38 <- glmer(Ausfall ~ ROIm_r + (1 + ROIm_r|WZ2) + (1 + ROIm_r|umsatz2), data = daten1, family = binomial)

summary(GLMM38)
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: Ausfall ~ ROIm_r + (1 + ROIm_r | WZ2) + (1 + ROIm_r | umsatz2)
   Data: daten1

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
109383.1 109475.1 -54683.6 109367.1   724763 

Scaled residuals: 
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
-0.309 -0.149 -0.113 -0.077 78.849 

Random effects:
 Groups  Name        Variance Std.Dev. Corr 
 WZ2     (Intercept) 0.535636 0.73187       
         ROIm_r      0.435871 0.66021  -0.74
 umsatz2 (Intercept) 0.002718 0.05214       
         ROIm_r      2.030239 1.42486  -0.44
Number of obs: 724771, groups:  WZ2, 87; umsatz2, 10

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -3.59208    0.09029 -39.786  < 2e-16 ***
ROIm_r      -1.96644    0.43865  -4.483 7.36e-06 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
       (Intr)
ROIm_r -0.209
```

Any advice is welcome!

Thanks!

Comment: I said it before and will say it again - it’s hard to interpret model output when the variables have German names (and we don’t know what they are supposed to measure) and we don’t know anything about the underlying study and research questions.  Any interpretation you might get in the absence of this information should be treated cautiosly.

Comment: Based on all your questions I have to seriously wonder why you are using a GLMM in the first place. All those questions can be answered by reference to the documentation for the `lme4` package and associated vignettes and papers, and in many answers on this site. My advice is to start with the following paper and if you still have questions, then ask some more focussed ones here.
https://www.jstatsoft.org/v67/i01/

Comment: Thank you! I will take a look at this paper.